# SQL Subquery using derived tables - Nested

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Here's the problem. I have three tables **tbl_history_type1**, **tbl_history_type2**, **tbl_player**. I want to get the total bets from history tables, based on the player, then get the sum of the result of these queries.

---

Here are the tables:

**tbl_history_type1**

- id
- player_id
- bet

**tbl_history_type2**

- id
- player_id
- bet

**tbl_player**

- id
- leader
- name

---

The query I am trying is below:

```
select id, name,
(
    select sum(total) from (
        select sum(bet) as total from tbl_history_type1 where player_id = a.id
        UNION ALL
        select sum(bet) as total from tbl_history_type2 where player_id = a.id
    ) as total_bet
) as b
from tbl_player as a where leader = 123
```

But I get this error:

```
Unknown column 'a.id' in 'where clause'
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
select id, name,
(
    select  sum(total) from (
        select player_id, sum(bet) as total from tbl_history_type1  group by player_id
        UNION ALL
        select player_id, sum(bet) as total from tbl_history_type2  group by player_id
    ) as total_bet where player_id = a.id
) as b
from tbl_player as a where leader = 123
```

Or you may try this approach, here you'll combine your record from both history table into one, since you want to sum all of the history records so no need to do sum of individual.

```
; with cte as (
select player_id, bet from tbl_history_type1
union all
select player_id, bet from tbl_history_type2  
)
select player_id , sum(bet) as total 
from cte 
inner join tbl_player as tp 
on cte.player_id=tp.id where leader = 123
```

Comment: Hi sir, the first one worked well. Thank you so much. You are the best!

Comment: @HannahMay: mark it as accepted to close... ;) . If you have time then study this second approach, it will help you further in other queries... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should join the aggregated by player_id so you don't need  accessing to tbl_player in  a subquery which is out of scope

```
select a.id, a.name, total_bet.total
from (
    select player_id, sum(bet) as total 
    from tbl_history_type1 
    GROUP BY player_id 
    UNION ALL
    select player_id, sum(bet) 
    from tbl_history_type2 
    GROUP BY player_id 
)  total_bet
INNER JOIN tbl_player a on a.id = total_bet.player_id
where a.leader = 123
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer and helping. I've got the answer now from DarkRob. Although, I still tried your answer but there's an error at this part 

select total_bet.total

I tried tweaking on it, I think that should inside a pair of parenthesis. Thanks. :)

Comment: answer  update  .. don't need  ()  just there is a wrong ' select ' .. anyway  check for the different perfomance  ..  in the answer  you choosed   the repeate the query fr each row ..  this is good for a single leader ..  but wha't happend when you need  a list??'